# Trigger to insert line items for all child products of a parent product

Tags: trigger, class

My data model has a custom object called Bids that is supposed to be like standard Quotes. Every Bid can have multiple Bid Line Items (master-detail), where each Bid Line Item represents a Product. Products are represented in a custom Product Catalog object that has a lookup to itself where there is a Parent Product (think Account to Parent Account). Bid Line Items have a filtered lookup to the child Products. I have checkboxes on the the Bid that are names of Parent Products: ABC, LMN, and XYZ.

What I am trying to accomplish is have the system create a Bid Line Item for each child Product of a Parent Product when the checkbox with the corresponding name of the Parent Product is checked. For example, checking ABC should create a Bid Line Item for ProductA, ProductB, and ProductC while checking LMN should create a Bid Line Item for ProductL, ProductM, and ProductN. I'm struggling to write this; will you please help?

Comment: Are you looking to just create the records or are you wanting to populate a Visualforce page once you click on the checkboxes and press Save? The records can easily be created with triggers for display on a new record, but a class/controller approach for refreshing a Visualforce page might be preferred depending on your use case. The latter would require a custom controller.

Comment: I'm looking to create records instead of the Visualforce approach. There's some complex pricing that can occur at each line item, so a Visualforce page isn't on the table right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger approach is simple to handle. I'll give you an outline of the general approach since I don't have all the details and don't want to write you trigger for you.

In this situation, I'd think you'll want your trigger to fire on After Insert and before Update of your Bid object to create BidLineItems which I'll refer to as BDI.

First thing you do is sort through trigger.new using if statements for Parent Products: ABC, LMN, and XYZ where the checkbox for each is == true.

You'll want to do that in a series of If statements, adding each Bid.Id to a separate update list for manipulation once you do. As in something like this:

```
set<Id>ABCIdset = new set<Id>();
set<Id>LMNIdset = new set<Id>();

For(Bid bd:trigger.new){
   If(bd.ABC_chk == true) add ABCIdset(bd.Id);
   If(bd.LMN_chk == true) add LMNIdset(bd.Id);
   ... etc
}
```

Use your sets to query for the products from each of the lookups from the parent as part of single query (assuming you need to query here am not totally clear on that).

Use what's returned to create the new records.

You'll also need to create a for loop that resets each of the checkboxes `bd.ABC_chk`, etc to `false` at the end of the trigger.

In the BeforeUpdate, you don't need to do any DML, just manipulate trigger.new. That makes it very simple because there's no recursion.

I don't see a reliable way to do a beforeInsert trigger without an Id to associate each record in trigger.new with. You could use an iterator and put everything into a map and do it that way, but that could be a bit "iffy", esp when trying to associate the BDI to the Bids since you won't have a reference Id. An AfterInsert is the safer way to go. For the sake of reusable code, you could make them both After triggers if you want to which is probably what I'd do.

```
// create and insert your BDI records for each BID
```

The problem with doing After triggers, is that you then need to handle recursion when you update the checkbox fields. At the beginning of your trigger, you'll need to test for a boolean flag to see if it's the "First Run".

```
    If (FirstRun == True){
        FirstRun = False;
        // continue with trigger code

        // at end of trigger 
    } // end if
}// end of trigger
```

Comment: You're welcome Tyler. Community etiquette is to help others by marking your question as solved through checking the answer that resolved your issue. If you don't, it leaves the impression to anyone who searches the topic later that your question wasn't answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: Of course. I just had to wait a little while before I could mark you as the winner. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem Tyler. Is just always odd to get a "Thank you" comment like yours without an upvote or having your post marked as answering the question.